# searchlayout REST API causing issue

Tags: rest-api, rest

Can somebody please let me know why /services/data/v28.0/searchlayout/?q=Account,Contact,Lead,Asset does not return data? It is mentioned in REST guide but on workbench it does not get executed and thrown error.

Error - Service not found at: /services/data/v28.0/searchlayout/?q=Account,Contact,Lead,Asset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below URL

> /services/data/v28.0/search/layout/?q=Account,Contact,Lead,Asset

I tested in workbench and this works fine as per document .

[image]

Comment: Hey Mohit, it works so the documentation is missing a forward slash. Thanks man:)